# Please how do I change the color of a black png picture to white?

Tags: html, css

I've made my research as much as I should but still can't help myself to find the white color of a black PNG image. I try to convert my black image PNG to white but to no avail. What hue rotate degree would make it white?

I tried using

```
filter: hue-rotate(38deg);
```

But didn't work. Also I iterated alot of numbers to get white color but to no avail.

Comment: Just a solid black image?

Comment: You can't achieve it with `hue-rotate`. Hue rotation yields the same "lightness". White and black don't have the same lightness. Start with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hue

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the problem is you have whitespace after hue-rotate. And for your question about changing the image from black to white, my solution is use `filter: invert(1)`.